# NLog default wrapper usage in JSON-config

Tags: c#, nlog

[Documentation](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#default-wrappers) says:

> Sometimes we require ALL targets to be wrapped in the same way, for example to add buffering and/or retrying. NLog provides `<default-wrapper />` syntax for that. You simply put this element *in the `<targets />`* section and all your targets will be automatically wrapped with the specified wrapper.

It also provides the following example:

```xml
<nlog>  
  <targets>  
    <default-wrapper xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="100"/>  
    <target name="f1" xsi:type="File" fileName="f1.txt"/>  
    <target name="f2" xsi:type="File" fileName="f2.txt"/>  
  </targets>  
  <targets>  
    <default-wrapper xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">  
      <wrapper-target xsi:type="RetryingWrapper"/>  
    </default-wrapper>  
    <target name="n1" xsi:type="Network" address="tcp://localhost:4001"/>  
    <target name="n2" xsi:type="Network" address="tcp://localhost:4002"/>  
    <target name="n3" xsi:type="Network" address="tcp://localhost:4003"/>  
  </targets>  
</nlog>
```

So, `<default-wrapper />` element should be a child of `<targets>` to be applied to each `<target>` within the same parent.

On the other hand, [Extended Json NLog Config Example](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json#extended-json-nlog-config-example) uses `default-wrapper` on the same level as `targets` element:

```json
"default-wrapper": {
    "type": "AsyncWrapper",
    "overflowAction": "Block"
},
"targets": {
```

So, I have the following questions:

1. Is the [Extended Json NLog Config Example](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json#extended-json-nlog-config-example) correct?
2. Will all targets from `targets` element be wrapped with the `default-wrapper`, placed out of the `targets`?
3. What if there are `default-wrapper` within `targets` and `default-wrapper` out of `targets` in the same configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there was some discussion about whether XML-config and JSON-config should be completely 1-to-1. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/pull/283

Because JSON-config represented targets-section as a dictionary of known target-names, then it didn't feel natural to have `default-wrapper` and `default-target-parameters` as reserved magic-strings.

1. Instead they were moved out of targets-section, as you have discovered from the documentation.
2. Yes all items in the targets-section will be wrapped, when using `default-wrapper`.
3. Have not tested what happens if placing `default-wrapper` and `default-target-parameters` inside the targets-section-dictionary. Maybe check the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) whether it complains about unknown configuration-items.

Notice more work is being done to give `default-wrapper` and `default-target-parameters` a better name, since it might not be easy to guess that they both apply to the targets-section. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/pull/500